# Detecting the linux distribution from java

Tags: java, linux

Is there a (preferably efficient, i.e. without executing binaries and parsing their outputs) way of detecting the Linux distribution in Java? As far as I know, `System` provides `os.name`, `os.arch` and `os.version`, which don't seem to help. For a typical Ubuntu installation they get these values:

> `os.name`: amd64
>
> `os.arch`: Linux
>
> `os.version`: 3.19.0-28-generic

What I need is whether the it's debian based, redhat family or others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think parsing a file *is* the way to go under Linux. You could of course do it only once.

The correct file to find such information on Linux would be `/etc/*-release`, which on my machine gives the following output:

```
$ cat /etc/*-release                                                                                        
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

You could then parse `ID_LIKE` variable which would give you the exact information you need (I can't guarantee that but I suppose it will always be in the 8th line on every Linux distribution).

Comment: I always hoped there is a more standard way, since this file is not enforced, and may not exist. But since I'm interested only in major dists, that's probably OK. However, correct way to handle it is a bit different: Man page says that `/etc/os-release takes precedence over /usr/lib/os-release. ... /etc/os-release should be a relative symlink to /usr/lib/os-release, to provide compatibility with applications only looking at /etc. A relative symlink instead of an absolute symlink is necessary to avoid breaking the link in a chroot or initrd environment such as dracut.`

Comment: Two final comments:8th line is not guaranteed, so one needs to parse line by line :) And the value is a space separated list, like `rhel fedora`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read one of these files:

```
/etc/release
/etc/lsb-release
```

On a more recent distribution you will also find:

```
/etc/os-release
```

Comment: It seems that release and lsb-release files are not that common, redhat derivatives don't include it. Since I'm only interested in recent distributions, maybe os-release will do. As @reachus mentioned, ID_LIKE is the variable to check.